# How to print `bash -xc` commands when using Docker Go SDK?

Tags: bash, docker, go, docker-api

I am trying to print Bash commands themselves from inside Docker using Go SDK. The following works:

```sh
docker run ubuntu /bin/bash -xc "echo test
echo hello
"
```

and prints the following results:

```
+ echo test
test
+ echo hello
hello
```

However, when perform the same operation in a Go application using Docker SDK, I get results of commands but not the commands themselves (this is the [default Docker SDK example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/#sdk-and-api-quickstart) modified to take multi-line commands):

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "io"
    "os"
    "log"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "github.com/docker/docker/pkg/stdcopy"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv, client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    script := `
        echo hello
        echo test
    `

    reader, err := cli.ImagePull(ctx, "docker.io/library/ubuntu", types.ImagePullOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, reader)
        
    resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
        Image: "ubuntu",
        Cmd:   []string{"/bin/bash", "-c", script},
    }, nil, nil, nil, "")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := cli.ContainerStart(ctx, resp.ID, types.ContainerStartOptions{}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    statusCh, errCh := cli.ContainerWait(ctx, resp.ID, container.WaitConditionNotRunning)
    select {
    case err := <-errCh:
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    case <-statusCh:
    }
    
    out, err := cli.ContainerLogs(ctx, resp.ID, types.ContainerLogsOptions{ShowStdout: true})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    stdcopy.StdCopy(os.Stdout, os.Stderr, out)
}
```

Is it possible to get these values from Docker logs?

Comment: Are they on the container's stderr?

Comment: Didn't know that `set +x` was writing to stderr. Thank you for the help!